# Proper Way to Pass Data Objects to Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am trying to work on sending an object of my scene class from a C# program to display it in a Unity program.

What are common ways to achieve that?

One option I came up with is WCF: The Unity program acts as client and the other C# program acts as server. Within each frame (i.e. in Unity's Update Function), the Unity program requests the current scene object from the other C# program in a request/reply fashion.

Are there better options? Is there a more *common* way to pass data objects to Unity?

Answer (score 0):

I might be stating the obvious here but have you considered the fact that a unity app is in a sense just a normal C# app?

So how would you normally get data in to a console app project if you just had visual studio and a blank new project?

Typically though, this varies depending on your requirement, if you are one of the many crazies out there building an MMO for your first game project you're gonna need some super powerful and scaleable server code and likely some custom binary "bit packing" serialization method to handle that compression between server and client.

However, if you haven't completely lost it then you are probably creating something like a first person shooter (unity was built for this) or something simpler that doesn't need constant streams of data that need low pings ... this is where your WCF scenario sits.

Unity does have some built in networking functionality but (and this is purely my opinion) it's really up to big game situations with a lot going on.

For say ... a minecraft clone, or a FPS that has up to say 16 players you could easily use the built in unity networking functionality beyond that you are in roll your own territory.

Here's some links to help you dig deeper ...

http://blog.ccoder.co.uk/?page=6

http://www.paladinstudios.com/2013/07/10/how-to-create-an-online-multiplayer-game-with-unity/

Comment: When I use WCF, I come up with the following option: My Unity app sends a request, and the other C# app (= host app) replies by sending an object to the Unity app. I could imagine doing this by using TCP as protocol with *SessionMode* enabled. However, I am looking for a more efficient way, without this request/reply fashion. Is there a way to **continuously** pass data objects from the C# app to the Unity app **asynchronously** via UDP (for example). Then I might need a worker thread in the Unity app, which permanently receives data objects from the C# app and stores them in the Unity app.